# How prove this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha_{n}=0$

Tags: limits

**Question:**

let $$\alpha_{n}(w)=\inf{\{|w\cdot v|:v\in Z^d \mbox{such that} ,0<|v|\le 2^n\}}$$

show that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha_{n}=0$$

where $d>2$

My try:sinc 
$$0<|v|\le 2^n$$
then 
 such  up to $2^n$

and  this problem is from this paper : Quasi-periodic motions in strongly dissipative forced systems  you can see: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.3009.pdf

Comment: What have you done up to now? What's $Z$?

Comment: Anything after "then"?

Comment: This is obviously false in the case $d=1$.

Comment: sorry,I have edit.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $w = (\alpha_1, \dots \alpha_{d - 1},1)$ (we can scale $w$ as we wish, so $1$ at the end is no loss of generality). According to [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) for any $N$ there are integers $p_i, q_i$ such that $|\alpha q_i - p_i| < 1/N$. So let $v = (q_1, \dots, q_{d-1}, - (p_1 + \cdots p_{d-1}))$. Then we have
$$
|w \cdot v| = |\alpha_1 q_1 + \cdots + \alpha_{d-1} q_{d-1} - p_1 - \cdots - p_{d-1}| < {d-1 \over N}.
$$

Because the sequence in question is obviously decreasing, this proves that it actually vanishes.